# Node CSV Parser

Tags: node.js, csv, filestreams

I'm using the node package 'csv', and I've run into an issue in the most obvious use case for the package and am not sure how to proceed. Package repo: https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv

I need to, 
1: read in a csv file, and perform a single operator for each line.
2: after the entire csv file has been read, perform an action and write the result to a new csv file.

I'm stuck on part one. Here is what I have after concatenating a bunch of (seemingly inconsistent) examples together.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');
var transform = require('stream-transform');

var outputMap = {};

var baseStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/locationTaxonomy.csv');


baseStream
 .pipe(csv.parse())
 .pipe(csv.transform(function(record){
  outputMap[record[2]] = record;
  return record; 
 }));
```

The preceding only gets through the first ~16 lines of the csv file, and then halts.
If I pipe baseStream directly to process.stdout, the file is read in completion. Any ideas as to how to accomplish this seemingly trivial task?

Comment: What's the error when it halts?

Comment: Does it always stop at the same spot? If so, could there be a formatting issue in the csv data? I've never used `csv` before though, but I have used [`fast-csv`](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) many times before on lots of data in production. You might try that module and see if it gets you any further. That may help you narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return statement in the transform stream handler caused the stream to halt. 
Removing it allowed the complete csv file to be read

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');
var transform = require('stream-transform');

var outputMap = {};

var baseStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/locationTaxonomy.csv');


baseStream
 .pipe(csv.parse())
 .pipe(csv.transform(function(record){
  outputMap[record[2]] = record;
  // return record;  // remove this line 
 }));
```

Comment: Had the exact same problem -- parsing stopped after exactly 16 lines (a `console.log()` within the `transform` function was called 16 times) regardless of how I shifted rows around in my data. I had a oneliner like this: `.pipe(transform(row => data.push(row)))` and the implicit `return` from the arrow function was enough to cause the problem. Refactoring to `.pipe(transform(row => { data.push(row); }))` allowed the parser to get all the way through the file. Don't understand why though!